# (maximum likelihood estimation) scipy.optimize.minize error

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, quantitative-finance, mle

I got the error

```
  File "C:/Users/", line 70, in <module>
    cal_PIN()
  File "C:/Users/", line 67, in cal_PIN
    cal_likelihood(selling_5_tick, buying_5_tick)
  File "C:/Users/", line 48, in cal_likelihood
    raise valueErr(result.message)
valueErr: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
```

I want to estimate the parameter in the pin model. The Log converted likelihood function is the same as the attached photo. The parameters to be estimated are (α, δ, μ, εB, εS). I coded the 3-steps-for-statement to set the initial value. I try to used `scipy.optimize.minimize` to estimate the parameter by applying Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

```py
import time
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(params, *args):
    # args={k1, k2, k3, kmi, buying_array[i], selling_array[i]}
    k1 = args[0]
    k2 = args[1]
    k3 = args[2]
    kmi = args[3]
    buying_array = args[4]
    selling_array = args[5]

    ini_a, ini_h, ini_eS, ini_eB = params
    return (-1) * (ini_a * ini_h * scipy.exp(k1 - kmi) + ini_a * (1 - ini_h) * scipy.exp(k2 - kmi) + (
                1 - ini_a) * scipy.exp(k3 - kmi) +
                   (buying_array * scipy.log(ini_eB + ini_h) + selling_array * scipy.log(ini_eS + ini_h) - (
                               ini_eB + ini_eS) + kmi))


def cal_likelihood(selling_array, buying_array):
    for ini_a in [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]:
        for ini_h in [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]:
            for z in [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]:
                time.sleep(1)
                i = 0
                for i in range(0, len(buying_array)):
                    ini_eB = z * selling_array[i]

                    cal_u = (buying_array[i] - ini_eB) / (ini_a * (1 - ini_h))
                    ini_eS = selling_array[i] - (ini_a * ini_h * cal_u)

                    k1 = ((-1.0) * (cal_u) - buying_array[i] * scipy.log(1 + (cal_u / ini_eB)))
                    k2 = ((-1.0) * (cal_u) - selling_array[i] * scipy.log(1 + (cal_u / ini_eS)))
                    k3 = (-1.0) * buying_array[i] * scipy.log(1 +
                                                              (cal_u / ini_eB)) - selling_array[i] * scipy.log(
                        1 + (cal_u / ini_eS))
                    kmi = max(k1, k2, k3)

                    initial_guess = [ini_a, ini_h, ini_eB, ini_eS]

                    result = minimize(f, initial_guess, args=(k1, k2,
                                                              k3, kmi, buying_array[i], selling_array[i]))
                    if result.success:
                        fitted_params = result.x
                        print(fitted_params[0])
                    else:
                        raise ValueError(result.message)


def cal_PIN():
    buying_5_tick = []
    selling_5_tick = []

    buying_5_tick.append(4035)
    buying_5_tick.append(3522)
    buying_5_tick.append(4073)
    buying_5_tick.append(3154)
    buying_5_tick.append(9556)

    selling_5_tick.append(1840)
    selling_5_tick.append(2827)
    selling_5_tick.append(4095)
    selling_5_tick.append(2602)
    selling_5_tick.append(2230)

    cal_likelihood(selling_5_tick, buying_5_tick)
```

I expected values where 0 < α < 1 and 0 < δ < 1, but something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you raise the error yourself it is obvious, that the minimization fails because of the error `Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss`.

Taken from [a scipy issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7536):

> This warning occurs when line search could not find a step size
>   meeting both Wolfe conditions and the Polak-Ribiere descent condition
>   within a certain number of iterations.

The results of your minimization don't seem to have any bound, as your objective function is just `*-1` some values. This results in rather big derivatives and could lead to some ill-conditioned Hessian. Such ill-conditioned matrix then leads to the linesearch-fail.
One option would be to change the objective-return to

```
return 1 / (ini_a * ini_h * scipy.exp(k1 - kmi) + ini_a * (1 - ini_h) * scipy.exp(k2 - kmi) + (
            1 - ini_a) * scipy.exp(k3 - kmi) +
               (buying_array * scipy.log(ini_eB + ini_h) + selling_array * scipy.log(ini_eS + ini_h) - (
                           ini_eB + ini_eS) + kmi))
```

This leads to the results beign in the required range of 0 < value < 1.

If this is not an optimal solution for you, try changing solvers. Find some options in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

Also some tips and tricks for youre programming. You can use itertools.product to avoid such nested loops. Instead of appending each value, just declare a list.

Here are the suggestions and the working code.

```
import time
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import itertools

def f(params, *args):
    # args={k1, k2, k3, kmi, buying_array[i], selling_array[i]}
    k1 = args[0]
    k2 = args[1]
    k3 = args[2]
    kmi = args[3]
    buying_array = args[4]
    selling_array = args[5]

    ini_a, ini_h, ini_eS, ini_eB = params
    return 1 / (ini_a * ini_h * scipy.exp(k1 - kmi) + ini_a * (1 - ini_h) * scipy.exp(k2 - kmi) + (
                1 - ini_a) * scipy.exp(k3 - kmi) +
                   (buying_array * scipy.log(ini_eB + ini_h) + selling_array * scipy.log(ini_eS + ini_h) - (
                               ini_eB + ini_eS) + kmi))


def cal_likelihood(selling_array, buying_array):
    list_iteration = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
    for (ini_a, ini_h, z) in itertools.product(*[list_iteration,list_iteration,list_iteration]):
        time.sleep(1)
        for i in range(0, len(buying_array)):
            ini_eB = z * selling_array[i]

            cal_u = (buying_array[i] - ini_eB) / (ini_a * (1 - ini_h))
            ini_eS = selling_array[i] - (ini_a * ini_h * cal_u)

            k1 = ((-1.0) * (cal_u) - buying_array[i] * scipy.log(1 + (cal_u / ini_eB)))
            k2 = ((-1.0) * (cal_u) - selling_array[i] * scipy.log(1 + (cal_u / ini_eS)))
            k3 = (-1.0) * buying_array[i] * scipy.log(1 +
                                                      (cal_u / ini_eB)) - selling_array[i] * scipy.log(
                1 + (cal_u / ini_eS))
            kmi = max(k1, k2, k3)

            initial_guess = [ini_a, ini_h, ini_eB, ini_eS]

            result = minimize(f, initial_guess, args=(k1, k2,
                                                      k3, kmi, buying_array[i], selling_array[i]))
            if result.success:
                fitted_params = result.x
                print(fitted_params[0])
            else:
                raise ValueError(result.message)


def cal_PIN():
    buying_5_tick = [4035, 3522, 4073, 3154, 9556]
    selling_5_tick = [1840, 2827, 4095, 2602, 2230]

    cal_likelihood(selling_5_tick, buying_5_tick)

cal_PIN()
```